# Black screen emulator Android Q Preview (Pixel 2)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-10.0

Strange issue here. I've just downloaded **Android Q preview** in my Android Studio to try it within an emulator. However, no matter what device type I select, when I start the emulator with the selected Q image I get black screen on the emulator without any kind of feedback. I've already tried to delete and recreate the emulator, as well as wiping its data. Below a picture of my emulator state at the moment. If I select another image of a different api version, everything works fine.
Below the Event log error:

> Emulator: Critical: UpdateLayeredWindowIndirect failed for ptDst=(736, 114), size=(300x21), dirty=(300x21 0, 0) (A device attached to the system is not functioning.) ((null):0, (null))

[image]

Comment: asking *Is anybody experiencing the same?* on SO is off-topic

Comment: @Selvin edited!

Comment: *Any clue?* is even worst...

Comment: You might edit the question instead of downvoting and avoiding providing details

Comment: I have experienced cold reboot removes this error

Answer (score 0):

Would just keep getting a black screen with nothing for hours with the tablets. What helped was actually the OPPOSITE of what most people here are recommending: after setting the tick box for 'Use Host GPU' and setting the target to the highest android

Comment: You know that when he just created new device there is no "user data" yet? ...so how this would help?