# Android Emulator doesn't boot on Windows 10

Tags: android-emulator

Basically, when I try to launch an emulator (old one or created from scratch doesn't change anything) I can see the phone's frame but Android doesn't boot.

Sometimes on the EventLog window I can see this error

```
Emulator: Critical: UpdateLayeredWindowIndirect failed
```

I tried many combinations of OS and phone but so far no sign of life, so I guess it's not related to any new update.

I'm currently using AndroidStudio 3.4 (but I had the same problem with the 3.3 version) on Windows 10.

**Update**: the error reported above appears only if I move the emulator to the second monitor, so maybe it's not related to the main problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Black screen emulator Android Q Preview (Pixel 2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55181532/black-screen-emulator-android-q-preview-pixel-2)

Comment: @Zoe not really, I tried with many combinations of Android Versions and devices, I found that question before but it didn't help me in any way